# The .vscode folder in Node project is usefull or not in latest visual studio editor?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

I'm using latest visual studio editor.

There is a `.vscode` folder in Node project, it it useful? Could I remove it?

It contains only one file `launch.json`:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Launch Program",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this folder is "Visual Studio Code integration" and is not necessary for your node.js project but without this, you can not continue developing on this project on visual studio with intellisense features.